# What is the post parameter for 'Items per page' sent by this web site?

Tags: http-post

I'm doing a little script for return results for this web:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geoprofiles?LinkName=geoprofiles_geoprofiles_prof&from_uid=58016926

My problem is that i only can get 20 results of 200. I know that i can change the items showed per page in the form "display settings". Where there are placed some options:

- Format
- Items per page
- sort by

With different values.

When you click on a POST method this options are sent to the server. I'm trying to figure out what are the parameters sent by this form.

For example, i'm able to change the display settings of "format" adding this post parameter to the URL:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geoprofiles?LinkName=geoprofiles_geoprofiles_prof&from_uid=58016926&format=text

I would like to know the parameter sent by post to change the option 'Items per page'

I have tried with:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geoprofiles?LinkName=geoprofiles_geoprofiles_prof&from_uid=58016926&format=text&items=50

Without result.

My question is, how I can know the parameter sent by post that change the "items per page"?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Well i work with python, but i'm not trying to do with a script. I'm only would like what parameter is sending by the web browser when i click in the form 'items per page'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chrome's Developer Tool or Firefox's firebug to see the details of your POST request.

E.g in Chrome, open the developer tool (ctrl+shift+i), and click the Network tab. Then make the POST request in the web app. You should be able to see the request and its response.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: The network Tab are cleared automaticatly when i send the post :(

Comment: I've played a bit with the URL you provided. It seems you can get around the refreshing by clicking on `Next` first. That would give your this URL: `http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geoprofiles`, for which the `Form Data` in Chrome shows `EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Geo.Geo_ResultsPanel.Geo_DisplayBar.sPageSize` and a few fields like that, which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Also note that, even if you can send the service with a different request, it is totally up to the service to decide what to return. It may only accept certain page sizes, or simply ignore the pass-in value.

Comment: Thank's!! However i'm lucky, there are API!